# sliding divs horizontally with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display my testimonials in my about us page. There I use 3 `divs` with styling horizontally to display 3 testimonials at once.

Here what im trying to do is I want to add some sliding effect with query to disappear 1st 3 `divs` and then need to load 2nd 3 `divs` with different testimonials. and so on.. I did HTML and CSS.. but no idea how to do it with query... can any body help me to do this..???

```
<div class="testimonials">
    <div class="cols">
        contents...1st time                    
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        contents...1st time       
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        contents...1st time       
    </div>

    <div class="cols">
        contents...2st time                    
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        contents...2st time       
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        contents...2st time       
    </div>

</div>


.testimonials {
    width: 640px; 
    height: 300px;
    //background: red; 
}

.cols {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    background: gray;
    float: left;
}
```

any comments, any idea greatly appreciated...

thank you..

Comment: You should have a look at this asnwer, it shows a good technique to implement [horizontal sliding between elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, lightweight javascript jQuery library:
http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

Comment: can I use it without right and left link.. can I make div sliding automatically... and also can I use div tag instead of ul tag

Comment: Its ok.. thanks for response.. But can I use it without right and left link.. can I make div sliding automatically... and also can I use div tag instead of ul tag

Comment: THANKS.. Can we do it vertically?

Comment: thanks... but I have a problem and I posted it with new post.. this is the link to it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000799/sliding-div-with-tiny-carousel-jqery-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great plugin for jQuery carousel

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

**Github:** https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel

or

**Github:** https://github.com/SSilence/simple.carousel

See the **jsFiddle** demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/GWhaz/

The first three `<li>` are showing first and three others are showing after 2000 sec.

Comment: thanks for response.. I want to change current 3 testimonials divs with next 3 divs automatically (after some time period)

Comment: Its ok.. thanks for response.. But can I use it without right and left link.. can I make div sliding automatically... and also can I use div tag instead of ul tag

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gZkUV/1/

```
$('#id').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

Comment: I need to let it work automatically. that mean.. 1st 3 testimonials load to the page and it should have sometime on the page and then load next 3 testimonials... and so on...

Answer (score 1):

if you surely want to use jquery, use something that is already built and out there in the community.that will be far secure and flexible option than anything u create from scratch.. Use something like 
`coin slider` or `jquery cycle plugin`. They have some specifics about the html markup on which u apply the plugin. Follow that and you are done.