# sliding div with Tiny Carousel jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to slide some divs horizontally with the Tiny Carousel jQuery plugin.

this is my html:

```
<div id="slider">

    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
            <div class="cols">
                <p>Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>ether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>r you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>ct knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>              
            <div class="cols">
                <p>promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>                
            <div class="cols">
                <p>with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.Whether you need to deliver product knowledge, promote a new service, or convey sales strategies, we make your message resonate, with materials that support your sales effort from the inside out.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="nav-btn">    
        <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>   
        <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Initialize
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('#slider').tinycarousel({ 
        display: 3, 
        pager: true, 
        interval: true,
        intervaltime: 10000,            
        //axis: 'y'
        controls: true 
        //animation: false
    });
});
```

This script is working, but when I insert 6 cols div sliding is not working. Why is that? I have given fix width and height to cols divs. Sometimes the contents in cols div are overflowing. In that case can I add a scroll bar to cols div?

Comment: this is my work so far http://jsfiddle.net/B3Zsz/1/

Comment: You need to change the jquery plugin slider attributes cols length upto your specified length. May be the default number for the attribute is 6

Comment: you can so this by .. making 6 div in a single colon and show only one colon at a time

Comment: sorry.. What I need to change in jquery plugin? but in fiddle It seems it is working properly?

Comment: http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

The URL shows the clear attributes for the slider jquery plugin. If any properties block the col length. So please check all the properties are given perfectly in ur plugin coding

Comment: Clearly, what do you want to do now. Now its having 10 cols and you are displaying 3 cols in a scroll. Now what is your desired result in this slider

Comment: I use this to display my tesimonials.. I made it to load 3 testimonials at one and then nother 3 and so on... now It ok.. Now can I make the left and right button always display on the page?

Comment: yeah sure. You can make this button always in your page. When the left count or right could reaches zero means the buttons are in hidden. You make it as shown with light opacity. So it will always display in your page

Answer (score 1):

In jquery plugin coding, the below function hides the button of next and prev. Replace the disable class into some other you want to display

```
function setButtons()
        {
            if(options.controls)
            {
                oBtnPrev.toggleClass('disable', iCurrent <= 0 );
                oBtnNext.toggleClass('disable', !(iCurrent +1 < iSteps));
            }

            if(options.pager)
            {
                var oNumbers = $('.pagenum', oPager);
                oNumbers.removeClass('active');
                $(oNumbers[iCurrent]).addClass('active');
            }           
        }
```

Change the below coding in CSS style

```
#slider-code .disable { visibility: hidden; } to


#slider-code .disable { visibility: display; }
```

Comment: thanks.. now can I know is there a way to add a scroll bar to my cols div when needed?

Comment: there is a another case.. assume left or right button disabling and a user continuing click on disable button and finally clicking on active button then that active button is not working.. reason is how many time user click on disable button he/she need to click that how many time on active button to make it work.. why is it?

Comment: Rithu.. Have any idea about this?

Comment: Why the user needs to click the disabled button? Can't understand what your desired result

Comment: user dont need to do so.. but someone mistakenly did so he/she need to wait with active button.. have any idea?

Comment: Call a function onclick the disabled button. Then count no of times the function called for a user, then depending on the count you can write your own functionality about what you want to do for that user