# save image proportion by screen size

Tags: html, css, image

I have div that is 500px heigh and 100% width. inside this div I want to add an image(that its width will be as the screen size), but when I add the image its size continue to keep the original size(its much more than 500px and get over another divs in my page). i tried to set the image div to width:100% and heigh:auto but the image won't change. i read and try this solution:http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/ but still, nit as I want.
here is my code:

```
<div id="main_pics" class="container">
<!-- photos here -->
<img src="5.jpg" id="image">

</div>

#main_pics{
margin-top: 57px;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}

.container{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
}

#image {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

i want it to look like this site:
http://www.panel-k.co.il

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use background-image and background-size: cover.

```
<div id="main_pics" class="container">
<!-- photos here -->
</div>

#main_pics{
margin-top: 57px;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-image: url("5.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.container{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
}
```

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/LLdp4eg4/1/

You could also add max-height: 500px to your image, but that would stretch it on large screens.

Comment: but i don't want just 1 pic, so when i set the image in the html file it's not working, my idea was to set 5 different images that will change every 10 seconds(via javascript). so when i set the image in the css file as background-image its won't help me. when i set the image in the html file its leak over all my page(because the image size) and cover my another divs.

Comment: That is kind of a separate question, but what you'll want to do is this:  instead of rotating images with javascript, you can rotate divs that each have a different background-image set.  If you right click on that sight you gave as an example (http://www.panel-k.co.il) in chrome or firefox and "inspect element", you'll see that's exactly what they're doing.  This SO question may help with that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987580/sliding-divs-horizontally-with-jquery-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely understanding the question, but it sounds like you might be looking for overflow:hidden.  So your css should have

```
#main_pics{
  margin-top: 57px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: but because of this solution image will get cut .. whole image will not be visible..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to make concessions.

First, you'll want to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent container, so that it  cuts your image if it is bigger than the allowed size.

Then, either use your image's full width, while stretching/cutting its height

```
img { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or stretch/cut its width to fit the div's whole height

```
img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Finally, you could also use something to restrict whichever is the highest, so your image never gets cut, but is always stretched

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Other options would modify the aspect-ratio of your image, making it plainly ugly for certain screen sizes.

A little side note about your example website: they used the second case. They used a fixed height with a very large image, and cut its sides.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to suggest using IDs is not good practice .Now solution for you problem .There are two options for problem:

1. #image{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
   }

But this will make your image stretched, if height that you want to have and width of image may not have proper aspect ratio.

So, 2nd option

```
#image{
 width:auto;
 height:500px;
}
```

This may make your image smaller in terms of width, but will not look stretched .

Choose anyone which is best suit for you :)